# Update Switch statement affects entire table

Tags: sql, ms-access

MS Access SQL. I'm doing a Update SQL statement using SWITCH.

```
Update Insurance Set [SellPrice]=SWITCH 
([Cover]=50, 4.2, 
[Cover]=100, 5.4, 
[Cover]=200, 6.8)
```

The 3 fields in the statements are updated correctly, but it blanks out the SellPrice column for all other entries. The statement is updating all rows, not just the 3 that I identified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usual behavior. Your update query always affects all rows, and a switch statement returns `Null` if none of the conditions are met.

You should filter the rows you want affected:

```
Update Insurance Set [SellPrice]=SWITCH 
([Cover]=50, 4.2, 
[Cover]=100, 5.4, 
[Cover]=200, 6.8)
WHERE Cover IN (50,100,200)
```

Alternatively, you could make the `SWITCH` statement return the current value if none of the conditions are met:

```
Update Insurance Set [SellPrice]=SWITCH 
([Cover]=50, 4.2, 
[Cover]=100, 5.4, 
[Cover]=200, 6.8,
True, SellPrice)
```

However, that will likely have worse performance and lead to more locks.

Comment: Thank you that was the help I needed!

Just a quick note, the last part should be "WHERE Cover In(50,100,200)"